# Django Redis connection error in heroku: Error 110 while writing to socket. Connection timed out

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I'm using Redis for caching in my Django project which is hosted on Heroku.

During Redis connection, on random times I got the below error message

> Error 110 while writing to socket. Connection timed out.

I'm using the below packages with versions

- python-3.6.8
- Django-2.2.2
- redis-3.2.1
- celery-4.3.0

Also, I'm access Redis using worker ( celery sometimes).

Can someone please suggest me to get rid of this problem or any other countermeasure to handle this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm having the same very issue and for some time I was thinking this may be caused by this issue https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1019. Recently this bug was fixed, I've updated kombu to `4.6.3`, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes for this--the most usual occurs where you have lots of cache evictions caused by the maxmemory setting on redis being too low.  Check to see your redis size using the redis-cli `stats` command and see if you need more memory to redis.